# How to resize images at phonegap

Tags: image, cordova, resize

I want to make some thumbnails for captured images. I think it improve perfomance of application (now my application use original sized images and looks a slower and slower if many images on the page). But I dont understand how to resize images more then one time. I know about phonegap resizing image (as option) when capture photo from camera, but it not working when I get image from imagegallery, and it not working more then one time.
I want to have 32x32 image, 150x150 image and image in original size.

P.S. I found image resizer plugin but it not working at phonegap 3.0 version.

Anybody know how to do this feature?

Comment: Would love to do this as well.  I'm using https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize but it incurs about a 50mb memory spike when it's working and can cause crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the PhoneGap-Image-Resizer plugin was forked, and now it may suit for 3.0 as well. The fork is located [here](https://github.com/skilesare/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, just wanted to update that the original repository is also updated and works well - 
https://github.com/RaananW/PhoneGap-Image-Resizer